# How to add widget to Samsung Smart TV App?

Tags: widget, publishing, samsung-smart-tv

I've created my own great widget for Samsung Smart TV. How i can publish it to Samsung Apps to share it with others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register on Samsung D Forum http://www.samsungdforum.com/

And here you can upload your app.
http://www.samsungdforum.com/MyWork/DmMyAppList